# Add to list of class in c# (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to create a short static function which I could call from everywhere to add into a List of Transform (in Unity), here's what I got:

```cs
public class MultipableTargetCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> targets;

    public static void AddToCamera(Transform target)
    {
        targets.Add(target);
    }
}
```

But I get an error message in Unity after saving my script "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MultipableTargetCamera.targets'".

I've tried many things and researched a lot but I can't find any solution that fits my needs.

I want to keep a List of Transform, I dont want use an array or to use a list of strings/ints. 
Any ideas?

Comment: dont make `AddToCamera` static.

Comment: What daniel said - and don't forget to initialize `targets` before you try to use it...

Comment: Thank you it works now, I had the idea of calling my function AddToCamera(...) easily when loading my players that's why I thought of a static function. But now it's ok I just had to find my script by code before executing the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is static while your field is not. To understand this, ask yourself: Imagine you initialize multiple of these objects, what is the right "targets" list?

Besides of the already commented fact that [static can be considered bad practice in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons), the answer is:

You can not access a non-static class member in a static function of that class.